# How to auto-focus RTE editor inside firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, focus, editmode

We have a RTE editor based on htmlarea which consists of content with editmode enabled inside an iframe. The question is how to automatically bring the focus into the editor?

Answer (score 2):

Where the `id` of the `IFRAME` is `myRTE`:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("myRTE");
if ( iframe && iframe.contentWindow )
   iframe.contentWindow.focus();
```